# SQL Specific Item on top

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by, case

I am having this query for a photo contest:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY entry_id DESC
```

The result gives 10 records with entry_id 10, 9, 8, 7, ......1

What can I do to pick a specific entry on the top? 
As there is a requirement if there is a refer ID, entry show first.

So the expected result should be: 4,10,9,8,7,6,5,3,2,1 if 4 if a refer ID.

Comment: I'm not playing in your lottery :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN entry_id = 4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), entry_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

for more Dynamic Approach create table value Function

```
create function OrderData(@a int)
returns @t table ( id int)
as 
begin 
insert into @t
SELECT * 
FROM ab
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN id = @a THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), id DESC
return;
end;
```

select * from  dbo.abc(4)

**output**
4,10,9,8,7,6,5,3,2,1

```
 select * from  dbo.abc(5)
```

**output**
5,10,9,8,7,6,4,3,2,1